# I hosted my site on Github - CSS does not working. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: html, css, github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTCWK.jpg)

I hosted my site on Github. And noticed that css file doesn't work.
Please help fix this problem.

[website](https://mojjo2016.github.io/CV/)

[Github repository link](https://github.com/MOJJO2016/CV)

I have checked links from html to css. Presumably it's not correct, but I don't know where is mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML code tries to import the css file as such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
```

hoewever, your folder is all uppercased (CSS), thus it has to be as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/styles.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CSS` directory is uppercase, so your path needs to be uppercase to reflect that.

Working: https://mojjo2016.github.io/CV/CSS/styles.css.

Not working: https://mojjo2016.github.io/CV/css/styles.css

Answer (score 0):

Your folder is uppercase but you referenced lowercase.